# MySQL: Get the full row with min value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the complete row with the lowest price, not just the field with the lowest price.

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
  `SubProduct` varchar(100),
  `Product` varchar(100),
  `Feature1` varchar(100),
  `Feature2` varchar(100),
  `Feature3` varchar(100),
  `Price1` float,
  `Price2` float,
  `Price3` float,
  `Supplier` varchar(100)
);
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO
  `Products` (`SubProduct`, `Product`, `Feature1`, `Feature2`, `Feature3`, `Price1`, `Price2`, `Price3`, `Supplier`)
VALUES
  ('Awesome', 'Product', 'foo', 'foo', 'foor', '1.50', '1.50', '0', 'supplier1'),
  ('Awesome', 'Product', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', '1.25', '1.75', '0', 'supplier2');
```

Select:

```
SELECT
  `SubProduct`,
  `Product`,
  `Feature1`,
  `Feature2`,
  `Feature3`,
  MIN(`Price1`),
  `Price2`,
  `Price3`,
  `Supplier`
FROM `Products`
  GROUP BY `SubProduct`, `Product`
  ORDER BY `SubProduct`, `Product`;
```

You can see that at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0543/1/0

I get the frist inserted row with the content of the column price1 from the second inserted row.

I expect to get the complete row with the right features, supplier and other columns. In this example it should be the complete second inserted row, because it has the lowest price in column price1.

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid SQL. But instead of rejecting it, MySQL chooses to simply return "indeterminate" results (which is for all practical purposes "random"). For more details see: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: What if there 2 items with the same min price for subproducs and product?

Comment: Then it does not matter which column is taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the MIN price rows and then JOIN those rows with the main table, like this:

```
SELECT
  P.`SubProduct`,
  P.`Product`,
  P.`Feature1`,
  P.`Feature2`,
  P.`Feature3`,
  `Price` AS Price1,
  P.`Price2`,
  P.`Price3`,
  P.`Supplier`
FROM `Products` AS P JOIN (
    SELECT `SubProduct`, `Product`, MIN(`Price1`) AS Price
    FROM `Products`
    GROUP BY `SubProduct`, `Product`
  ) AS `MinPriceRows`
ON P.`SubProduct` = MinPriceRows.`SubProduct`
AND P.`Product` = MinPriceRows.`Product`
AND P.Price1 = MinPriceRows.Price
ORDER BY P.`SubProduct`, P.`Product`;
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0543/20

Here what I have done is to get a temporary recordset as `MinPriceRows` table which will give you MIN price per SubProduct and Product. Then I am joining these rows with the main table so that main table rows can be reduced to only those rows which contain MIN price per SubProduct and Product.

Comment: Thank you! What if SubProduct may be NULL? With your solution those rows are ignored. See at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de837/2/0

Comment: @Hativ3 in that case, what should be the output? Meaning what are you expecting in the output.

Comment: SubProduct and Product can be seen as a unit. If SubProduct is NULL it is simply a product that has no subproduct, you can see it as a new (or another) independent product. Then SubProduct can be just output NULL. Do you understand?

Comment: I have extended my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed1c2/1/0 What I expect is that it should also show a row with NULL and Product.

Comment: Use null-safe comparison `<=>` in the JOINing clause, like this: `P.SubProduct <=> MinPriceRows.SubProduct`. Updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed1c2/2

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT
  `p`.`SubProduct`,
  `p`.`Product`,
  `p`.`Feature1`,
  `p`.`Feature2`,
  `p`.`Feature3`,
 `p`.`Price1`,
  `p`.`Price2`,
  `p`.`Price3`,
  `p`.`Supplier`
FROM `Products` `p`
inner join (select MIN(`Price1`)as `Price1`
            From `Products`
           ) `a` on `a`.`Price1` = `p`.`Price1`

ORDER BY `p`.`SubProduct`, `p`.`Product`;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0543/24

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
SELECT
P1.`SubProduct`,
P1.`Product`,
P1.`Feature1`,
P1.`Feature2`,
P1.`Feature3`,
P1.`Price1`,
P1.`Price2`,
P1.`Price3`,
P1.`Supplier`
FROM `Products` P1
INNER JOIN `Products` P2 ON  P1.SubProduct = P2.SubProduct AND P1.Product = P2.Product
WHERE P1.Price1 < P2.Price1
```